# Learning materials for doing analysis (calculus) in a mechanized way

Tags: learning, provers, resources, calculus, analysis

Can we collect (or maybe even write) tutorials and guides on doing analysis in various Proof Assistants? Community wiki style?

---

I was reading Lawrence Paulson's blog (highly recommend!) the other week and https://lawrencecpaulson.github.io/2021/11/17/Cauchy-Schwarz-example.html in particular. It employs pretty specific rules, tactics and theorems relevant to calculus.

I have an impression analysis-formalizing libraries for other proof assistants develop some specific tactics and notations too. For instance I looked over https://github.com/math-comp/analysis/ and https://github.com/lecopivo/SciLean

So the question is: where can I learn about that specifics?

For *Program* Analysis we have very comprehensive guides like Software Foundations, PLFA, Concrete Semantics and Functional Algorithms, Verified (plus their "fan translations" from one Proof Assistant to another). Do we have (or can we have) anything comparable for *Mathematical* Analysis?

---

A [related but narrower question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/256/what-are-good-books-for-learning-about-proof-assistants-for-functional-analysis) was mostly misunderstood and poorly answered as far as I can tell (but decided to mention for completeness).

Comment: There is a [survey article](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00806920/file/article.pdf) about formalizing real analysis, which you might be interested in...

Comment: Thanks @AlexNelson that's an interesting paper indeed! But I'm still interested in collecting _learning_ materials on the topic. :)

Comment: Ah, my mistake! At any rate, there is a sad lack of material that you seek...for **any** field of mathematics. There are maybe a half-dozen papers doing _what_ you ask (acting as a guide on _formalizing_ mathematics in a proof assistant), but none of them on analysis _in general_.

Comment: Like, one of the half-dozen resources which may be interesting is John Harrison's PhD Thesis, which was focused on the different ways to formalize the real numbers in a proof assistant. It was around 150 pages, iirc, and worked within HOL Light.

Comment: @AlexNelson yeah, I kinda looked around and didn't immediately find anything on analysis like, say, Isabelle/HOL tutorial. I though maybe this question will motivate someone to write one? 

Comment: I did a quick search search of Lean community YouTube channel and found few videos about analysis. 
Calculus and integration: https://youtu.be/p8Etfv1_VqQ
Topology and filters: https://youtu.be/hhOPRaR3tx0
Measure theory: https://youtu.be/yH3-zE0bYCU

Comment: I'm author of mentioned library SciLean. The library is mainly focused on doing computations rather then building and proving theory like most of the other work using theorem provers. What are you mostly interested in?

Comment: @tom thanks for the great links to videos! In the scope of this question I'm mostly interested in tutorials and guides on _practical_ use of Proof Assistants to solve Calculus problems (I'm thinking about "Software Foundations" volume II teaching basics of Hoare Logic for a toy language Imp, but for Calculus). I guess that's mostly proving theorems, but calculations are interesting too! :)

Comment: I know very little about Hoare Logic, but from the quick look it looks similar to some kind of categorical reasoning. To do automatic/symbolic  I mostly follow this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00746 which defines specialized categories for differentiation and rewrite rules for expressions in them. From my limited understanding, it looks like one could frame this in term of Hoare logic too. This would be quite specialized and only useful for computing derivatives. However, the paper is in Haskell, not theorem prover so not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @tom WOW, that's a cool paper, thanks!

When referring to Software Foundation I meant not the Hoare Logic specifically but the "tutorial"-style presentation, like "to do this and this we write this and that and use this tactic that does that and that, then we go one step further and do this next thing"... I would very much like to see something similar for Calculus in a Proof Assistant. :)

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if such a tutorial exists. If you find something, please post it here.

Comment: Your question prompted me to write something down. It is more 'how to use symbolic differentiation in SciLean' but it can give you an idea how to do calculus computations in a theorem prover https://lecopivo.github.io/SciLean/doc/differentiation_in_scilean.html

Comment: Also few more links can be found in this question https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/379/pdes-and-proof-assistants

Comment: @tom thanks! :D

Comment: @tom your (WIP) tutorial "how to use symbolic differentiation in SciLean" is precisely an example of what I had in mind! Could you please post it as an answer? I'm not sure I can accept it as a final one, but I still think it will be much more visible and useful for the community. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of the mentioned library [SciLean](https://github.com/lecopivo/SciLean) and this question prompted me to write down a bit about how I do symbolic differentiation in Lean: [Differentiation in SciLean](https://lecopivo.github.io/SciLean/build/doc/literate/differentiation_in_scilean.html) (note: it is still work in progress)

It is more of a guide how to use SciLean to do symbolic differentiation rather then a guide how to build something like SciLean. Hopefully you can get the main idea from it and maybe get inspired.